# Swift: getting character from string (ascii value)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, string

I'm trying to get the character value in ascii and also the character at index.

I have this `Objective-C` any of you would know the conversion to `swift`?

```
po [strToSort characterAtIndex:i]  // character x
U+0078 u'x'
po [strToSort UTF8String][i]
x
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: you can directly subscript string with an `Index`

Swift doesn't allow you to subscript `String`s with an Integer index. Instead you can construct an index to pass in.

```
let str = "String with some characters"
let index = str.startIndex.advancedBy(5)
let character = str[index]
print(character) // "g"
```

For more information on why you can't treat strings as a direct sequence of characters, you can find more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30).

Essentially to be properly unicode compliant, sometimes multiple characters can be combined to create a single character in the final string. This causes issues with naive counting and indexing.

If you want a utf8 representation of the string, `String` provides a `utf8` property as well as a `unicodeScalars` property for getting the code point for each character.